# sscanf while reading 2 integers, extracts 0 for first digit

Tags: c, scanf

I am reading formatted data with

`sscanf(buf,"%d %d",&a,&b)`;

`data format = (unsigned short SPACE unsigned short)`;

but when i read it only successfully extract 2nd integer value from buffer for first it extracts 0. I am checking with (`printf("nRecvd %d and %d",a,b)`) I am reading from socket and I verified buffer values. All is ok untill sscanf.

```
char buf[MAXBUFL];
unsigned short a, b;
if (sscanf(buf,"%d %d",&a,&b) != 2)
      snprintf (buf, sizeof(buf), "data error\r\n");

    else
      {
      printf("\nRecvd %d and %d",a,b);}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You are scanning into `short` variables which means that you must tell `sscanf` that.  You need:

```
if (sscanf(buf,"%hd %hd",&a,&b) != 2)
```

This is explained in the man page for `scanf`.